# Spring Formatters Configuration Options

Tags: java, spring

Is there a difference between the following configurations for Spring formatters?

Config 1)

```
public class AppConfigurator extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
.....
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addFormatter(new DateFormatter());
}
```

Config 2)

```
public class AppConfigurator extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
.....
@Bean
public FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionService(){
    FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean formattingConversionServiceFactoryBean = new FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    Set<Formatter<?>> formatters = new HashSet<>();
    formatters.add(new DateFormatter());
    formattingConversionServiceFactoryBean.setFormatters(formatters);
    return formattingConversionServiceFactoryBean;
}
```

Appendix:

(Custom created formatter for java.util.Date DateFormatter.class)

```
public class DateFormatter implements Formatter<Date> {

public DateFormatter() {
    super();
}

@Override
public String print(Date object, Locale locale) {
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = createDateFormat();
    return dateFormat.format(object);
}

@Override
public Date parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
     final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = createDateFormat();
       return dateFormat.parse(text);
}

private SimpleDateFormat createDateFormat() {
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    return dateFormat;
}

}
```

Comment: Yes the second one is more work and there is no garantue that it will be used by all configured adapters.